# Make iPhone apps think no external monitor connected

Tags: applications, jailbreak, display, settings

How can I make iPhone apps think that no external display is connected?

I am using a 30-pin to A/V adapter, and an iPhone 4 GSM with 7.0.4 jailbroken.

I was hoping to use iFile to change a setting on the iPhone, but I'll try any solution.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Tumbleweed. Can anyone help?

Comment: I saw this question the day that you posted it, and I've come back to it every day since then. I know where it should be, but I just can't seem to find the exact method that you need to override.

Comment: @Andrew Larsson Please, any clues to this would be greatly appreciated by not only me, but by everyone looking for this on google. It is something that I have not been able to find for at least a month now.

Comment: @Andrew Larsson You can make apps think that you are on wifi when actually on 3G; I don't see why you can't make apps think that there is no external display. It's puzzling!

Comment: It's possible. I'll keep looking.

Comment: @Andrew Larsson Yes, thank you. You said you know where it should be... Can you tell me that location so I can help you out? Thanks again!

Comment: It's in `AVFoundation` somewhere.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson I think I've found something: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Chapters/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009530-CH1-SW51 See `allowsExternalPlayback`

Comment: Actually, I found this developer article a few days ago. I haven't had the chance to go over it in detail, but I'm pretty sure it mentions a method that allows you to see if there are any displays connected. You could just override that method with a homemade tweak (or maybe even Flex) to say that there are never any external displays connected. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html

Comment: @AndrewLarsson Yeah, I think that this: `if ([[UIScreen screens] count] > 1)` is probably the key. I'd have to find out where `UIScreen screens` is and set it to 1. Do you think that it's in AVFoundation? I'll keep looking. I think I'm going to run Grep through the whole /System directory to look for that variable. BTW, thanks for the link!

Comment: Here's the developer page on `UIScreen`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html

Comment: After looking at these developer documentation articles, I'm realizing that you'd have to write a tweak to do this, and that it's not as simple as just changing a .plist entry or throwing together a Flex mod. `UIScreen::screens` is an `NSArray` of all of the screens attached to the device. It's not set anywhere in any files. It's managed in Objective-C code inside of the `UIKit` framework.

Comment: I took a shot at it, and I put together a Flex patch that may or may not work. I don't have an A/V adapter, so I can't test it. Do you have Flex?

Comment: @AndrewLarsson I've never heard of it. How could I get it? BTW, thanks for all the help. I really appreciate it! Yeah, if you tell me how to get the tweak up and running, I'll test it out with my A/V adapter and let you know if it worked.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson I think you mean this: http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/flex-the-most-powerful-jailbreak-tweak.395011/

Comment: @AndrewLarsson I installed Flex 2 on my iPhone. Can you give me a link to your tweak (or tell me how to make it). I really appreciate it!

Comment: In Flex, go to the cloud tab, go to SpringBoard, and then install "Disable External Screens." Let me know if it works.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson I fixed it! I didn't try your method yet... That'll probably do it too, but I patched the app that was giving me problems. Let me post it as an answer so you can see it...

Comment: @AndrewLarsson See comments in my answer below. Thx.

Comment: Oh, it looks like it hasn't gotten through the Flex patch approval process yet (it used to not have any filtering back when Flex first came out). For your specific application, go under `UIKit`, then go to `UIScreen`, then choose `+(id) screens`. Go back to the list of Units for the patch, and then make sure to set the one we just added to always return `NULL`. That's what the patch I put together uses. If it works, let me know, and then I'll post it as an official answer here on this question. If you let me know which app it is, I could make a more specific one that works if this one doesn't.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson Alright... let me try that... Its the `TV Go` app by Xfinity BTW...

Comment: @AndrewLarsson Sorry about the delay. I've been busy. I tried doing what you said in your last comment; however, the `TV Go` app still displayed `Were Sorry...` and greyed out the display. If you have the app (it's free) I'd really appreciate it if you could find out what to turn off to stop it from displaying this message. I've tried using `DisplayOut` BTW in order to mirror the screen, but the app displays the message as an overlay anyway. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AndrewLarsson See comment above. Thx.

Comment: Oh, thanks for reminding me. I'll take a look at that app.

Answer (score 1):

It Works!

I installed Flex per @AndrewLarsson and entered the name of the app that was detecting the external display.

I then went under `UIKit`, then searched `UIScreen` and returned `pass-through` on `displayOut_actualScreens`.

When I tested it with my AV adapter, the app did not know that there was an external display connected!

Many thanks to @AndrewLarsson for his help! Without it, I couldn't have figured it out.

**UPDATE: False alarm. It wasn't working. I had gotten overly excited and missed the fact that IT DIDN'T WORK!!! I'm really sorry about that...**

Comment: @AndrewLarsson False alarm... I thought it was working... But apparently not. I couldn't find "Disable external screens" in the list.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson Where is "Disable external screens"?

Comment: @AndrewLarsson http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1550201

Comment: @AndrewLarsson Can you send me the properties for "Disable external screens" I can then recreate it on my end since I can't find it. Thanks much!

Comment: Note that @mentions to Andrew here don't go to Andrew as he has not commented on this post. To ping someone, do it in a post they have commented on (e.g. your question) or in chat.

Comment: @grgarside I thought that was only if you did not include a "mention"...

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean — see [How do comment replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for more info

Comment: @grgarside Sorry, I thought that "mentions" got to the user no matter where they were put. I stand corrected. Thanks for the tip!